# How to combine the two time and day value in moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment js and I am struggling with combining 2 inputs in one dateTime
,

[image]

I have 2 input values -

from 1st, I get day e.g. monday, tuesday, wednesday.. Saturday etc..

from 2nd, I get date time Wed May 26 2021 09:20:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```
 dayDate  Wednesday
 timeValue  Wed May 26 2021 09:20:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

I want to combine both the value and have one date time and then need to convert that in milliseconds.

for e.g today is 26, user selected Saturday from one input and time from other,
I have to take the next coming Saturday date and time from given second input.

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In first you create a moment using the date you get from time picker, after you set the day of week with `.day()`.

For convert the date in milliseconds you can use `.format('x')` (x is the Unix milliseconds timestamp)

```js
function calculateDate () {
  const dayDate = "Saturday" // replace with your get element
  const timeValue = document.getElementById("timeValue").value;

  console.log('Complete date: ', moment(timeValue, 'HH:mm').day(dayDate).toDate());
  console.log('In Milliseconds', moment(timeValue, 'HH:mm').day(dayDate).format('x'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input type="time" onchange="calculateDate()" id="timeValue">
```

If you get a complete Date Obejct from the time picker it will not necessary to specify the format in moment constructor, the code will become `moment(timeValue).day(dayDate).format('x')`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, `Complete date:  Invalid Date `comes Invalid, "moment": "^2.24.0", in package json, It seems `.day(dayDate)`

Comment: In which case? I tryed again in jsfiddle with moment 2.24.0 and this is the result of complete date log `"Complete date: ", [object Date] { ... }`. Can you write a snippet of your code?

Comment: It's working fine with `timeValue = new Date()`, with this it's not working `timeValue  Wed May 26 2021 09:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

Comment: anything wrong with my time what I get from 2nd input, because `timeValue = new Date()` works but` Wed May 26 2021 09:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` is not working, any format issue,

Comment: I just noticed, My time is coming as string. `"Wed May 26 2021 09:30:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
` Can you guide me how to fix this..

Comment: Had you try to convert your string in date `const timeValue = new Date('Wed May 26 2021 09:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)');`. Here it's work for me https://jsfiddle.net/AlTheLazyMonkey/0oufamq8/8/

Comment: Yes I got the solution, `timeValue = new Date(time);` by this it's no more string..

Thanks for the answer..

Comment: I have one doubt, I wanted to have the future dates only, this will be for scheduler, can startof week will take the future date,

Comment: A simple way, but not efficent i fyou schedule for a large period, it's to use `moment(timeValue, 'HH:mm').add(count, 'weeks').day(dayDate).format('x')` where count it's the number of weeks to add. For set the day it's not necessary so use `.startOf()`.

Comment: Alternativly you can sum the milliseconds that compose a week (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) at result of `.format(x)` for get the next week event, multiply per 2 for the event in 2 week in the future ecc.

Comment: All this 2 last solution are awful for me, but i don't know how you store this info for schedule the events

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232902/discussion-between-javascript-coder-and-althelazymonkey).

Answer (score 2):

Using [`startOf('week')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) and [`day('Saturday')`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/)

**Explanation**

`timeValue` - Wed May 26 2021 11:35:27 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

`startOf('week')` - Sun May 23 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

`day('Saturday')` - Sat May 29 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

```js
const dayDate = "Saturday"
const timeValue = new Date()

console.log(moment(timeValue).startOf('week').day(dayDate).toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit, how startof week will take the future saturday, and what if today is saturday

Comment: @JavascriptCoder I tried explanation. Anyhow you can find a better explanation with examples in the provided document link

Comment: ` dayDate  Saturday
timeValue  Wed May 26 2021 09:20:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
final scheduleDateTime  Invalid Date` It's coming as Invalid date,  `updatedDateTime = moment(timeValue).startOf('week').day(dayDate).toDate();

  console.log("final _saveInternalSetting scheduleDateTime ", updatedDateTime); // this to be passed in put call..`

Comment: `startOfWeek =moment(timeValue).startOf('week');
   updatedDateTime = moment(startOfWeek).day(dayDate).toDate();
  console.log("final _saveInternalSetting scheduleDateTime ", updatedDateTime); // this to be passed in put call..`.  this is not working, it gives Invalid Date..  `day(dayDate).toDate()`

Comment: anything wrong with my time what I get from 2nd input, because `timeValue = new Date()` works but ` Wed May 26 2021 09:20:34 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` is not working, any format issue,

Comment: I just noticed, My time is coming as string. `"Wed May 26 2021 09:30:26 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"
` Can you guide me how to fix this..